# How to stretch (scale) image on a UIView?

Tags: image, uiview, stretch

How can i take an image and stretch it to fill the screen on my `UIView` (320/460)

I am loading and placing it, however as you can see, some scaling is needed.

[image]

Thank you!

```
CGRect gameArea = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green_background.jpg"]; 
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
[myImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];

UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:gameArea];

[topView addSubview:myImageView];    

[[self view] addSubview:topView];
```

Answer (score 4):

Like I said in my comments above to Shamsiddin's post, the UIImageView needs a size to know where to stretch to. Here I'm using the same size of the UIView. I've added another answer because the code to UIView is missing. So here's the complete code.

```
// Area of the UIView and UIImageView
CGRect gameArea = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

// Create UIImageView with Image
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green_background.jpg"]; 
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:gameArea];
[myImageView setImage:[backgroundImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:3 topCapHeight:3]]; 
[myImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

// Create UIView and insert subview
UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:gameArea];
[topView addSubview:myImageView];    
[[self view] addSubview:topView];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CGRect gameArea = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green_background.jpg"]; 
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:gameArea];
[myImageView setImage:[backgroundImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:3 topCapHeight:3]]; 
[myImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
```

Comment: Shamsiddin is right, I think. You've forgotten to set the UIImageView size, that's why it's not stretching. You need to set up the same size for the UIView as for the UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
UIView *view;
view.ContentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in my own iOS5 app, i needed to dynamically set the background image and scale it. Imagine you are doing this in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated`

```
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imageview];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageview];
```

So we create the view, set it's scaling mode, add the bg image, set it as the subview in the main view and then push it to the back so it does not occupy any other subviews.